# How can I underline part of the text like iPhone SMS?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uilabel

I use an UILabel to show my text, in a multi-line and UILineBreakModeWordWrap mode, and the maximum width is 200.
For example, here is the text:

```
I really really want to underline first word and second word, could you help me?
```

And I want to underline "first word" and "second word".

If the text is shown in a single-line mode, with sizeWithFont method of NSString, I can easily calculate the position of "first word" and then override - (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect to draw the line.

But in multi-line mode, I don't know how to get the position. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's quite some discussion about the missing NSAttributedString on the iPhone and people start building their own text layout systems to work around this. There are some projects going in this area. You may want to have a look at the [Three20 project](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master) and its [TTStyledTextLabel](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/blob/b78944872623673b1329688fd59a5708f048bef8/src/Three20/TTStyledTextLabel.h).

Comment: TTStyledTextLabel is exactly what I wanted.  
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Use a UIWebView to display your text. That's what Apple recommends for rich text.

Comment: Yes, UIWebView can definitely solve my problem, but wouldn't it be too heavy to just show a sentence?

Comment: I have this feeling about UIWebView, too. But nevertheless, it's what Apple recommends. See my second answer.

Comment: Well, that's a while ago now. I think I remember them saying that at WWDC. Anyway, in 2009 there was no other built in control that was capable of rich text.

Comment: Here's a WWDC 2011 session in which Justin Garcia explains how to use a UIWebView to implement "desktop caliber" rich text editing on iOS: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/includes/rich-text-editing-in-safari-on-ios.html#rich-text-editing-in-safari-on-ios